# how to install libpython3.6m.so.1.0 on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, python3, gcc, arm, cross-compilation

I tried updating my cross tools for arm64 on my x86-64 ubuntu 20.04 machine.
The installed cross tools gcc-arm-11.2-2022.02-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf from arm.
When I run the aarch64-none-elf-gdb, it gives me this message.

```
ckim@ckim-ubuntu:~/test$ aarch64-none-elf-gdb
aarch64-none-elf-gdb: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I found I have some libpython packages on my system.

```
ckim@ckim-ubuntu:~/test$ dpkg -l | grep libpython
ii  libpython2-stdlib:amd64                    2.7.17-2ubuntu4                     amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (Python2)
ii  libpython2.7:amd64                         2.7.18-1~20.04.1                    amd64        Shared Python runtime library (version 2.7)
ii  libpython2.7-minimal:amd64                 2.7.18-1~20.04.1                    amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 2.7)
ii  libpython2.7-stdlib:amd64                  2.7.18-1~20.04.1                    amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 2.7)
ii  libpython3-dev:amd64                       3.8.2-0ubuntu2                      amd64        header files and a static library for Python (default)
ii  libpython3-stdlib:amd64                    3.8.2-0ubuntu2                      amd64        interactive high-level object-oriented language (default python3 version)
ii  libpython3.8:amd64                         3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.4             amd64        Shared Python runtime library (version 3.8)
ii  libpython3.8-dev:amd64                     3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.4             amd64        Header files and a static library for Python (v3.8)
ii  libpython3.8-minimal:amd64                 3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.4             amd64        Minimal subset of the Python language (version 3.8)
ii  libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64                  3.8.10-0ubuntu1~20.04.4             amd64        Interactive high-level object-oriented language (standard library, version 3.8)
```

and when I do `sudo apt search libpython`, I see only libpython3.8 or libpython3.9 stuff. What should I do in this case?

### ADD

I found by `dpkg -L libpython3.8`, I have libpython3.8.so.1.0 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu directory. So I went there and did
sudo ln -s libpython3.8.so.1.0 libpython3.6m.so.1.0
and the debugger runs (though I couldn't see the change I wanted from this new version). I'm not sure this is the correct method.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading from Ubuntu 18 to 20, I got the same problem as you:

```
dpkg -L libpython3.8
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libpython3.8.so.1.0 libpython3.6m.so.1.0
```

This helped me a lot, thanks!